# How to uncheck all the checkboxes in child of Expandable listview?

Tags: android

Actually i want to uncheck all the CheckBoxes in child of ExpandableListView.It only clear the CheckBoxes of one Expanded Group...When i expand two or more group and uncheck all the CheckBoxes then it does not work.

```
 public void removeAllChecks(ViewGroup vg) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //View convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items, null);
    childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

    View v = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            try {
                v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check_filter);
                //((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
                childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            } catch (Exception e1) { //if not checkBox, null View, etc
                try {
                    removeAllChecks((ViewGroup) v);
                } catch (Exception e2) { //v is not a view group
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

> here is my adapter class code

```
    package com.zobrando.contests;

    /**
    * Created by hp on 11/14/2015.
    */

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class RightDrawerListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private List<String> navDrawerItems;
    private ArrayList<RightNanDrawerItems> childItems;
    Integer mst,mlcnt=0,mcnt=0;
    private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
    private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

    HashMap<String, List<String>> popuplist;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer,      boolean[]>();

    private static final Integer[] Icons = {
            R.drawable.trophy,
            R.drawable.buld,
            R.drawable.brand,
            R.drawable.target,
            R.drawable.age,
            R.drawable.participants
            //R.drawable.reward
    };


    public RightDrawerListAdapter(Context context, List<String>    navDrawerItems,HashMap<String, List<String>> popuplist){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        this.childItems = childItems;
        this.popuplist = popuplist;

     }

     @Override
     public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int chlidPosition) {
        //String pos = String.valueOf(groupPosition);
        return this.popuplist.get(this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition))
                .get(chlidPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.navDrawerItems.size();
     }

     @Override
     public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
     }

     @Override
     public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
     }



    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup    parent) {


        final String childText = getChild(groupPosition,   childPosition).toString();

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items, null);
            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
            childViewHolder.mChildText=              (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.popuplist);
    //            TextView txtTitle = (TextView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.popuplist);
            childViewHolder.mCheckBox=      (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_filter);
    //            checkBox =    (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_filter);
            convertView.setTag(R.layout.pop_up_list_items,childViewHolder);
        }
        //selectedStrings.clear();
    //        txtTitle.setText(childText);

        //checkBox.setText(childid);


        else {
            childViewHolder=      (ChildViewHolder)convertView.getTag(R.layout.pop_up_list_items);
        }

        childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);
        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(groupPosition)){
            boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(groupPosition);
            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked[childPosition]);
        }
        else {
            boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(groupPosition)];

            // add getChecked[] to the mChildCheckStates hashmap using      groupPosition as the key
            mChildCheckStates.put(groupPosition, getChecked);
            // set the check state of this position's checkbox based on the
            // boolean value of getChecked[position]
            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean    isChecked) {
                //Toast.makeText(context,"groupPosition="+groupPosition+"-   childid="+childPosition,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
                database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (isChecked){
                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(groupPosition);
                    getChecked[childPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(groupPosition, getChecked);
                    database.execSQL("insert into tblcheckfilter    (groupid,childid)"
                               +"values('"+groupPosition+"','"+childPosition+1+"')");

                }
                else
                {
                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(groupPosition);
                    getChecked[childPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(groupPosition, getChecked);
                    database.execSQL("delete from tblcheckfilter where    groupid='"+groupPosition+"' and childid= '"+childPosition+1+"'");
                }

                dbHelper.close();

            }
        });

        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        //// clear filter
    //        Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("select menustatus, menucount from     tblusers", new String[]{});
    //        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
    //            do {
    //                mst = c1.getInt(0);
    //                mcnt = c1.getInt(1);
    //            }while (c1.moveToNext());
    //        }
    //
    //        c1.close();
    //        dbHelper.close();
    //
    //        if(mst == 1){
    //            mlcnt=mlcnt+1;
    //            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    //
    //            if(mlcnt.equals(mcnt)) {
    //            Toast.makeText(context,"mcnt="+mcnt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    //                database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //                database.execSQL("update tblusers set menustatus=0");
    //                dbHelper.close();
    //
    //            }
    //        }
        //checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CheckchangeListener(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.popuplist.get(this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        String headerTitle =  getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.right_drawer_list_items, null);
            groupViewHolder =new GroupViewHolder();
       groupViewHolder.mGroupText=       (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
          groupViewHolder.icons=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);

        }else {
            groupViewHolder=(GroupViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(headerTitle);
        groupViewHolder.icons.setImageResource(Icons[groupPosition]);

//        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
//        imgIcon.setImageResource(Icons[groupPosition]);
//        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

//        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getIcon());
//        txtTitle.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    public final class GroupViewHolder {

        TextView mGroupText;
        ImageView icons;
    }

    public final class ChildViewHolder {

        TextView mChildText;
        CheckBox mCheckBox;

    }

    public void ClearFilter(){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items,    null);

        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
        childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox)      convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_filter);
        convertView.setTag(R.layout.pop_up_list_items, childViewHolder);
        if (childViewHolder.mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    public void removeAllChecks(ViewGroup vg) {

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //View convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items,    null);
        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

        View v = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list_items, null);

            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                try {
                    v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                    childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox)      v.findViewById(R.id.check_filter);
                    //((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
                    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                } catch (Exception e1) { //if not checkBox, null View, etc
                    try {
                        removeAllChecks((ViewGroup) v);
                    } catch (Exception e2) { //v is not a view group
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

      }

     }
```

Comment: What you are passing in to the `removeAllChecks();`

Comment: i am calling this from another activity and passing expandablelistview in it...

Comment: @Nigam can you please help me? through code

Comment: The best way to use is, if you are storing checked check boxes value into any array, then make all the elements of that array to false and notify the adapter.

Comment: i am saving all the checked states in hash map

Comment: Can you just post the adapter code.

Comment: atleast `getView()` method code and the hashmap name.

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter (customAdapter) include a method call updateAllCheckBoxes();

```
updateAllCheckBoxes(bool isChecked) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        AdapterItem info = this.getItem(i);
        info.isChecked = isChecked;

        // info (add a boolean isChecked in you adapter item to store the state of checkbox i.e. checked or not. )
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your getView(). according to state of variable(isChecked), select or deselect the checkbox.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //or you could pass it from outside (your activity) through constructor
            //LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();

            //resourceId is passed through adapter's constructor
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, null);
       }


       ((CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox)).setChecked(this.isChecked);

}
```

Comment: what's exact problem for you, plz elaborate more

Comment: actually i want to uncheck all the checkboxes....but issue is that when i expand a single group and unckeck then it works fine but when i expand more than one group and uncheck then it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your removeAllChecks to this, it will do all the stuff what you want to do.

```
public void removeAllChecks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(i)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mChildCheckStates.get(i).length; j++) {
                mChildCheckStates.get(i)[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And one thing I noticed that, in `getChildView()`, you are checking for whether it contains, any key or not, which is not good. Do all these all these stuffs inside your constructpr, It will speed up your listview.

Comment: null pointer exception at this line: for (int i = 0; i < this.getGroupCount(); i++)
its crashing on getGroupCount()

Comment: I don't think so, may be its crashing in the inner loop.

Comment: yes! when i changed the outer loop condition then it crashed in the inner loop...

Comment: What you changed in outerloop?

Comment: i changed outer loop to: for (int i = 0; i < =6; i++)

Comment: What is that 6, and why you used like that?

Comment: actually the number of groups are 6 that's why i changed it to 6

Comment: i have tried with updated code but its not working and crashing in the inner loop

Comment: In inner loop or if condition?

Comment: I am getting error on this line, (int i = 0; i < this.getGroupCount(); i++) {.    if i fix getGroupCount to 6 groups...its doing nothing...but Group value is not available on this...and the exception is still NULL

Comment: But, it should not., Ok Let me see

Comment: Basically, There are multiple groups and every group has multiple child view...and every child has checkbox..on clear button..we just want to uncheck all the child of all groups...

Comment: Yup, i got it, but it shouldn't crash in getGroupCount;

Comment: May be in your code, some thing is wrong, once check with getGroupCount in your code, may be its returning null.

Comment: Please find the crashing report:   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.zobrando.contests.RightDrawerListAdapter.getGroupCount(RightDrawerListAdapter.java:79)
            at com.zobrando.contests.RightDrawerListAdapter.removeAllChecks(RightDrawerListAdapter.java:276)

Comment: Here getGroupCount is becoming null, not in my code.

Comment: can you share you code. we just want to see definition of group. where you defined.

Comment: Here, `navDrawerItems` becoming null.